# Can alg be used for the formal semantics of a language?

Tags: first-order-logic, metaprogramming

This library “generates all models of a first order theory”: https://github.com/andrejbauer/alg

Is it able to take the formal semantics of a programming language, like:

- x86: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3314221.3314601
- JavaScript: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2737924.2737991

and generate all possible expressions / valid sequences of commands, under some length limit, *k*? What does a preparation of the specification of the language look like, for use in alg?

Comment: Does "possible expressions" count as models?

Comment: I have no idea, let me know what you think please. I think I should just study Knuth’s chapters on induction since that is I think what I am obsessed with. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601798/knuth-algorithm-on-constructing-a-proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theoretically** speaking, it might be possible because Alg can axiomatize any single-sorted first-order theory with equality. It's not clear to me how to do it directly, though.

**Practically** speaking, you would get a horribly inefficient thing that wouldn't get anywhere. Alg is not meant for this sort of thing.

You're probably better off looking at *logic programming*, except you'd want breadth-first search rather than depth-first. Perhaps someone knows of a prolog-like program that can do breadth-first search? Maybe a modern prolog implementation?

Comment: Cool, that appears to be very relevant, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082799/breadth-first-search-in-prolog I think they may also be: https://hal.science/hal-03537517/document https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_breadth-first_search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783590/game-tree-modulo-symmetry-in-prolog I’ve been looking for this for a long time, trying to develop my own algorithm to build all possible combinations in a formal system / expressions in a language, and evaluate them under some metric. Does that have a broader term, in the field?

Comment: I feel like in category theory you’re basically finding the product/coproduct object, the direct/indirect limit, right? (Like the power set can be the limit of a set, I believe). The metric would be a functor taking the objects to some other object in a different category? Is there some advanced categorical study of this - a way to identify “optima” in a category under a functor? Has it been applied usefully to discover anything, or programmed to perhaps discover something? (I think this, now: https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4859/pdf/35.pdf)